# running grunt and jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, gruntjs, grunt-cli

I have jenkins running grunt tasks. I have jenkins running the command:

```
grunt name-of-tasks
```

on the master server (I have a master/slave setup) it is able to run grunt tasks correctly, however, on the slave servers, it is unable to run grunt tasks. I get the error:

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...[31mERROR[39m
[31m>> [39mError: Cannot find module '...
[33mWarning: Task "example" not found. Use --force to continue.[39m
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing some of `npm` modules. Try to run `npm install` before `grunt`